# Version control ideas besides SVN or Git?

Tags: linux, windows, version-control

I'm looking for some version control method or system i could use - but SVN or Git won't work.

- I write code, allone, no team
- I use several different computers, some private, some from my employer
- Most PCs run Win 10, some Linux (Debian derivates)
- I want my code to be synced across this PCs
- I'm looking for a self-managed solution, i don't want to use Github or similar
- On the computers from my employer, i can't use WebDav or SSH connections

My first attempt was to set up a small git server on my NAS, which works fine when i use my own hardware. Fiddling around, i found out that i can't use that on my workplace hardware, having SSH (and WebDav, afaik) connections disabled. And i can't get the permission to use that.

Version control in general is new to me. Shame on me, but i actually used to copy my code files manually, if i wanted to change something. Syncing between computers was done using that NAS as a data-cloud - on my private hardware. On the workplace hardware, i can access my cloud-storage with a webbrowser and download the relevant files from there. The sync client, which i'm using private, doesn't work on my employers PCs either.

As coding isn't my full time job, it's not that big problem as it might seem. But it's still not a good workflow, so i'm looking for something that might help me to get things done in a better way.

Any ideas what method or system might work in my situation?

Comment: For personal projects I often use just a bare git repository on a USB flash drive. Can you connect such a device to your workplace machine(s)?

Comment: @choroba: Unfortunately not, USB is blocked, too. But that's a nice idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Git hosting services don't actually use WebDAV – they use Git's "smart" HTTP transport, where the client makes ordinary HTTPS GET and POST requests to a CGI backend. This means it will work with nearly all proxies and firewalls, and is about as efficient as SSH (much more so than WebDAV).

The "smart" HTTP transport is supported by all self-hosted Git platforms, such as Gitea and Gogs.

If you prefer doing things by hand, see [*git http-backend(1)*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend) and the related [Git Book chapter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) for instructions on configuring this on your own server. (Note that this is *only* the Git-protocol service and doesn't include a web UI, though it can be colocated on the same URL as Gitweb/Cgit if necessary.)

The same idea also works with Mercurial (hg), whose [hgweb](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Allowing_push) WSGI webapp provides both a web UI and a clone/push service over regular HTTPS.

Comment: I mentioned WebDav, as that's what SVN relies on, if i understood that correctly. but thank you very much for mentioning this self-hosted platforms - and that using them, i won't have such issues as with ssh! Sounds promising, now i have something to look for. Do you prefer one of the mentioned platforms for a reason, or are they very similar, if one has just basic needs and not much experience in the field?

Comment: I haven't actually admin'd any of those platforms (only git-http-backend for public read-only access). Overall, both Gitea and Gogs were originally based on the same code and they share the same general ideas, but the former seems to be somewhat more actively developed. I think both are preferrable over trying to self-host GitLab CE... // SVN relies on WebDAV heavily; Git does _technically_ support WebDAV and it's what some people coming from SVN try to use at first, although that support is almost completely obsolete given the existence of git-http-backend.

Comment: Thank you! I've already found informations on how to run Gitea on a Synology NAS, so i guess this could work and solve my problems. Great! :)